# How to code else if in short if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For example, I have code with short if statement and how can I code else if in this code?

```
 var age = 16;

 age > 18 ? console.log("> 18") : console.log("< 18");
```

That would work like this code

```
var age = 16;
if (age > 18){
    console.log("> 18");
}else if(age == 18){
    console.log("= 18");
}else{
    console.log("< 18");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shortHand if else-if and else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265123/shorthand-if-else-if-and-else-statement)

Comment: Nesting ternary expressions is bad practice because any perceived benefit is offset by losing readability.

Comment: Focus more on readability and maintainability and less on how "short" you can get the code.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to never use ternaries if the return value isn't going to be used or if it is genuinely easier to read.

Comment: `console.log((age===18 ? "=" : age > 18 ? ">" : "<") + " 18");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it with ternary expression,

```js
var age = 16;
console.log(age === 18 ? "=18" : age < 18 ? "< 18" : "> 18")

var age = 19;
console.log(age === 18 ? "=18" : age < 18 ? "< 18" : "> 18")

var age = 18;
console.log(age === 18 ? "=18" : age < 18 ? "< 18" : "> 18")
```

Comment: This is the same as Kobe's answer

Comment: @ChrisG really !!!, please have a look again

Comment: Thanks this answer helped me

Comment: Look at what exactly? It's not exactly the same obviously but it adds nothing to it

Answer (score 1):

A hybrid approach is recommended in this case:

```
var age = 16;

if (age == 18) {
    console.log("= 18");
} else {
    console.log(age > 18 ? "> 18" : "< 18");
}
```

Comment: Might not be as short as other awnsers, but definitly more readable !

Comment: Yes but I want to write in short way.

Comment: Totally understand. That is the reason I recommended hybrid approach. best of both worlds. If you run your code through code analysis tools such as SonarQube for example, it would define your expectation as a code smell. It is important to know when to stop minification.

Answer (score -1):

The `if` way could also be written like this:

```js
var age = 16;
if (age > 18) {
  console.log('> 18')
} else if (age == 18) {
  console.log("= 18");
} else {
  console.log("< 18");
}
```

So, you could use a nested ternary in the style of the code above:

```js
var age = 16;

age > 18 ? console.log('> 18') : age === 18 ? console.log("18") : console.log("< 18")
```

Note, it would be more efficient to write the ternary inside console.log, since you are always returning similar values (in this case, strings):

```js
var age = 16;

console.log(age > 18 ? age === 18 ? '18' : '< 18' : '< 18')
```